# Xcode - green variables x black variables

Tags: iphone, xcode, syntax-highlighting

I have two classes. One was basically created using the same files as the second, with some other modifications, but they are essentially the same, specially regarding to their declaration files (that have something like this)...

```
@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>

// delegate protocol definition

@end


@interface myClass : UIView {
 id myObject;
 UIView *oneView;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<myClassDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *oneView;
```

and then I have @synthesize oneView, delegate; on .m

The code you see is common to both classes.

Inside the implementation of both classes, I use several times both objects, for example:

```
[delegate doStuff]; // <-- do you see this blue delegate here? Xcode put it green when it is declared on .h first.
```

on my first class, every occurrence of oneView or delegate are shown in green by Xcode (see image below). On the second class, they are shown in black. I generally consider this green word to be some kind of acknowledge that the variable has been identified on the declaration and is "global" for that class. Generally black variables mean local instances.

The question is that I am having problems of one of these variables being deallocated, without my intention, exactly on the class where it is shown in black.

There's no release of that variable in the class (except on the dealloc), but objects created using both classes live all the time while the app is running.

What may be wrong?

[image: exampla of what I consider correct]

thanks in advance.

Comment: The delegate var must not be released - it is an assign-property!

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the code. oneView is declared as retain. Ant this oneView is seen in black in one class, and on green on the other. The class giving me problems is the one where the variable is in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have marked a property as assign, you MUST NOT release it in that class, ever.  That includes in dealloc.  It seemed from your writeup that you were releasing the delegate in dealloc.  Note that you should set the variable to nil in dealloc or if you know you are done using it, so if the delegate is accidentally released somewhere else you will not crash.

As for the coloring, the only thing I think might affect this is if you have imported "MyClassDelegate" in both files the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose black color of word in XCode editor means that XCode hasn't detected this word as instance variable. Maybe you forgot to declare `delegate` instance variable? And the error thus must be in deallocating  of `delegate`.

**Note:** you can change syntax highlighting colors in XCode by looking in it's preferences: 
[image]